# Asynchronously set or override CSS properties under specific @media query using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I know how to set one or more CSS properties for every matched element using such jQuery function: `$( 'p' ).css( 'color', 'red' );` But how can I set CSS properties under specific media query's rule?

Can you give me an idea how to set the attribute of the color *(lets say)* of `<p>` element **under specific media query** using JavaScript/jQuery as what you see below?

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    p {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

### Update

Lets say we have a color picker control *(such in WP Customizer)* and an HTML element that will asynchronously change its color under `@media (max-width: 600px)` based on the color control. Now how can I asynchronously set CSS properties under specific `@media` query based on a color control?

Comment: Let me add this, I want to **override CSS properties** and not to use the `if` statement.

Comment: You cannot do that without if statement!

Comment: If you want to edit the stylesheet I think you can't with JavaScript (someone correct me if I'm wrong). You need server side language, PHP for example.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) (no jQuery required)

something like this:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is less than 600 pixels */
}
```

**Snippet** ( value changed for demo )

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 800px)").matches) {
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName('P');
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    p[i].style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on dippas answer but checking the width all the time to apply the style when change:

```js
var mediaquery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)"),
        text = document.querySelector("p");

    function mediaChange(mediaquery) {
      if (mediaquery.matches) {
        text.style.color = "blue";
      } else {
        text.style.color = "red";
      }
    }
    mediaChange(mediaquery);
    mediaquery.addListener(mediaChange);
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to to use the window.with with the resize option.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 800){  
        $('element').css({color: 'red'})
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could even do that using jQuery `resize()` method. `Media query` too in other words is `if condition`, i.e. we are checking that `if` @media (max-width : 600px) `max-width is 600px or lessthan 600px` so at that point perform changes in my `DOM`.

Try this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ztrr1qk/).